# How do I limit all program's FPS?

Tags: windows-8.1, framerate

I play a lot of games. I also have an awesome computer. I usually get around 300-500FPS in a game.

I heard that using more FPS than my monitor can handle (60) will waste power. How do I limit **all** programs at **all** times to 60fps (or less, I suppose).

I want to basically add a cap to all programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most graphics driver control panels have a setting to wait for vertical refresh. This results in 60fps on a 60hz LCD as that is how often a vertical refresh happens. Forcing it to always on  will limit all games to that fps.

AMD Catalyst Control Center example:

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to do it without special software? I'd prefer to do it within windows.

Comment: Any graphics chip capable of the FPS you posted I know about has a control panel like posted above which is installed by Windows 8.1 along with the graphics driver. View the desktop, right click and select NVIDIA Control Panel, AMD Catalyst Control Center etc.

Comment: I manually uninstalled those. I don't like them.

Comment: I know of no general way in Windows itself. There are various third party utilities that try to do it but most are out date since demand dropped when most driver control panels made a setting available for it.